# how to overwrite specific part of batch with another batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, overwrite

I have very long list of commands in my batch, where a lot of strings depend on file name of the file I work with. So I would like to somehow rewrite those parts of code with diferent variation so I could avoid manualy search for these bits and rewrite them one by one in my long batch whenever I would work with diferent file name of alt file. just an example:

**Batch-1-(endlesly-long-bat).bat:**

```
IF EXIST "*.webm" (
REN "*.webm" "COOL-PROJECT.webm"
)
FOR %%a in ("COOL-PROJECT.webm") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~na.mp4"
IF EXIST "COOL-PROJECT.mp4" (
MD "COOL-PROJECT"
)
REM so on and so on. order, type or commands itselfs are irelevant
```

**Batch-2-(overwriting-bat).bat:**

*this bat needs to scan content of "Batch-1-(endlesly-long-bat).bat" and look for specific string of characters "COOL-PROJECT" and when it founds all of them, then it will replace those characters with another string of characters "WORST-NIGHTMARE". so based on input mask phrase (COOL-PROJECT) this batch needs to rewrite specific informations in first batch. (I guess trought opening it within notepad? or there is a cmd way?)*

Comment: Maybe a good solution: open in Notepad or whatever editor and replace it with `%~1`. Then you can start the batch file with a startup parameter, for instance `Batch1.bat "COOL-PROJECT"`. No need to do any replaces after that.

Comment: And if you want to do the replace from a script, you can pick FART, or any of the other answers to [this almost duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir).

Comment: Some examples would have clarified matters.

Comment: Bad idea - there is no need to write a script that requires editing between runs. You should follow Golez Trol's and Stephan's advice. It is extremely rare that you would ever require a batch script edit another batch script as part of normal operation.

Comment: @GolezTrol - nice handy idea, I will use it, but not as solution of my question. that FART and other suggestions are also interesting. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use the same string over and over again, it's a good idea to work with variables instead of the string itself.

```
set "filename=COOL-PROJECT"
IF EXIST "*.webm" (
REN "*.webm" "%filename%.webm"
)
FOR %%a in ("%filename%.webm") do ffmpeg.exe -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy "%%~na.mp4"
IF EXIST "%filename%.mp4" (
MD "%filename%"
)
REM so on and so on. order, type or commands itselfs are irelevant
```

This way, you have to edit only one line instead of many strings distributed in the whole file.

As this is a "one-time-Task" only, you can easily use "find and replace" with your Editor.

Als Golez' idea is a very good one. Just replace `set "filename=COOL-PROJECT"` with `set "filename=%~1"` and start your batchfile with the desired Name as Parameter:

```
Batch1.bat "COOL-PROJECT"
```

No need to edit anything ever again.

Comment: thx. if I may confirm... is "Name as Parameter" (`Batch1.bat "COOL-PROJECT"`) same as `Title "COOL-PROJECT"` ?

Comment: uhm - no? First is a Parameter to the batchfile, second is a command to set the Windows title. See `title /?`